# Calculate $\int\limits_C (x+z)dx+\sin(y+z)dy+\cos z\,dz$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $$\int\limits_C (x+z)\,dx+\sin(y+z)\, dy+\cos z\,dz$$
>   where $C$ is a curve where cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and surface $x+y+z=1$ intersect.

**My answer:**

Let $C=\partial S$

I will use Stokes.

$$\int\limits_C (x+z)\, dx+\sin(y+z)\, dy+\cos z\, dz=\iint\limits_S -\cos(y+z)dydz+dzdx+0\cdot \, dxdy$$
$$=\iint\limits_S -\cos(y+z)\, dydz + dzdx$$
Let $\Phi:[0,2\pi]\times[0,2]\ni(\phi,r)\longrightarrow (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi,1-r\cos\phi-r\sin\phi) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrization of surface $S$.

And then I just calculate surface integral yes?

Comment: You just need to be a little cautious for choosing the surfaces when you apply Stokes, that is all you need.

Comment: Is mine wrong application of stokes? Can you elaborate more?